# Change Icon on IPython Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm running notebooks on different servers, and I want a quick way to see what server a notebook is running on.

I'd like to change the little icon here:
[image]
From the default one to something I make, but can't find documentation for how to do this - anyone know?

Comment: Just a note - changing the icon.ico file in IPython/html/static/base/images doesn't seem to work

Comment: Answer below is correct.  For the record the approach I listed above would have worked too, but editing the icon in Apple's Preview doesn't work - you can edit the icon and it will look like it changed and everything, but still the original image will remain hidden, and that's what's gets displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the favicon of the notebook you have to create individual profiles for the desired servers. For each profile (e.g. *custom*) add the favicon to `.ipython/profile_custom/static/base/images/favicon.ico`.
 Now start your server with the newly created profile like
`ipython notebook --profile custom` and voila you have your custom favicon.
Note, that the favicons are typically .ico files as discussed e.g. [here](https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/).

I tested this with a prominent favicon and now have notebooks looking like
[image]

This is also used by some of the available kernels like e.g. IJulia.